# AngularJS - jquery plugin SelectBoxIt after ng-options finish populating select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm populating a select box using AngularJS with the following code:

```
<select ng-model="department" 
        ng-options="dept as dept.name for dept in departmentList" 
        class="fancy">
    <option value="">-- select an option --</option>
</select>
```

But I need to render this SELECT box using the SelectBoxIt jquery plugin.

A hard-coded version of the SELECT works just fine as I have the initialization of SelectBoxIt at the bottom of the controller handling this section of the page:

```
$targetSelects.selectBoxIt({
            theme: "bootstrap"
            , downArrowIcon: "arrow"
            , showFirstOption: false
        });
        $targetSelects.on({
            "open" : onOpen
            , "close" : onClose
        });
```

I am now thinking that SelectBoxIt initialization is happening before the angular-populated SELECT box is finished populating.

Does this seem likely?  If so, how might I solve this?  I'm thinking this is probably a case of using a Deferred object, but am not sure where to inject this.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Update

I re-implemented the plugin call as a directive.  It does work.  It initiates the drop-down as a SelectBoxIt select box, but it is still being done BEFORE angular has populated the dropdown using ng-options....

```
.directive('fancySelect', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var $targetSelects = $(element),
                selectConfig = {
                    theme: "bootstrap",
                    downArrowIcon: "arrow",
                    showFirstOption: false
                };

            function onOpen(event){
                $(this).data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").downArrow.addClass("drop-up");
                log('onOpen');
            }

            function onClose(event){
                $(this).data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").downArrow.removeClass("drop-up");
                log('onClose');
            }

            $targetSelects.selectBoxIt(selectConfig);
            $targetSelects.on({
                "open" : onOpen,
                "close" : onClose
            });
            $targetSelects.selectBoxIt('refresh');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: controllers should not be used for DOM manipulation, general practice is initialize external plugins from directives. Will likely have to update scope model from callbacks of the plugin , and use `$apply` since angular won't be watching the event

Comment: A simple timeout might work (something like `$timeout(initPlugin)`), but sure I wish angular had an *init* event for directives that you could listen to.

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't using Angular.js, you could use the **populate** option to add options to your SelectBoxIt dropdown: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/#PopulateOptions

Since you are using Angular, if there is some event that you can listen to once your select box is populated, then you could call the SelectBoxIt **refresh()** method to update your dropdown, like this:

```
    // Once your original select box is populated
    $('select').selectBoxIt('refresh');
```

Comment: `if there is some event that you can listen to once your select box is populated`, this is precisely what is needed, an event for `ng-options` finishing rendering.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to watch the model and then fire an event on the next digest cycle.

```
scope.$watch(model, function() {
    scope.$evalAsync(function() {
        // event
    });
});
```

I've written this up properly here: [Detect when ng-options has finished rendering](http://adamkdean.co.uk/blog/read/93/detect-when-ng-options-has-finished-rendering).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved part of the problem here, which *may* work for some, using $timeout in the directive.
Whilst this, for me, solves the problem of the options being rendered, unfortunately, at the time of writing this, I can't get them to function!

```
.directive('fancySelect', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     $timeout(function() {
        var $targetSelects = $(element),
            selectConfig = {
                theme: "bootstrap",
                downArrowIcon: "arrow",
                showFirstOption: false
            };

        function onOpen(event){
            $(this).data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").downArrow.addClass("drop-up");
            log('onOpen');
        }

        function onClose(event){
            $(this).data("selectBox-selectBoxIt").downArrow.removeClass("drop-up");
            log('onClose');
        }

        $targetSelects.selectBoxIt(selectConfig);
        $targetSelects.on({
            "open" : onOpen,
            "close" : onClose
        });
        $targetSelects.selectBoxIt('refresh');
    }
  }, 0);
};
```

});